# Select Rows From Answer Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have QUESTIONS_TB and ANSWERS_TB

Is there a single query that will return all rows from a QUESTIONS table AND all rows in ANSWERS table (for a related table based on an ID)

The answers table could have more than one answer for a question so in a single query I want to select all the answers rows that is related a question.

In this query I am selecting the answers rows to a particular question but sub-query is not allowing me select two columns.

so it throws this error: **operand should contain 1 column(s)**

How can I achieve this in a single query?

```
$question_id = 56; //example question id...
$sql = "SELECT Q.*, 

      (SELECT A.answer_body 
      AS body, A.answer_id 
      AS answerid, A.ask_id 
      AS askid, A.user_id 
      AS answered_by_user_id

      FROM $answers_table A 
      INNER JOIN $questions_table Q  
      ON A.ask_id=Q.question_id 

      WHERE A.ask_id='{$question_id}') answers,


      (SELECT COUNT(v.vote_id) FROM $votes_table v WHERE Q.question_id=v.ask_id AND v.vote_type=0 ) votes_down,
      (SELECT COUNT(v.vote_id) FROM $votes_table v WHERE Q.question_id=v.ask_id AND v.vote_type=1) votes_up,
      CONCAT(m.firstname,' ',m.lastname) author_name,m.username u_name FROM $questions_table Q 
      LEFT JOIN $main_table m ON Q.user_id=m.user_id
      WHERE Q.question_id='{$question_id}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the question and the answers for it you can do this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
   Q.*, A.answer_body AS body, A.answer_id AS answerid, 
   A.ask_id AS askid, A.user_id AS answered_by_user_id
FROM
   $questions_table Q
LEFT JOIN
   $answers_table A on A.ask_id = Q.question_id
WHERE
   Q.question_id = $question_id
```

This will return all of the answers for a single question. You can change the question in the WHERE statement.

If you want all answers returned joined to their question then remove the WHERE statement.

Comment: I want to retrieve all the answers plus the question. I want to loop through the answers... and it is possible a question may not have an answer.

Comment: @jamesOduro I have updated my answer with the new code. Left joins will return all rows in the left table even if there is no match on the right. That would return all questions if there is no answers.